# Using MVVM toolkit for connecting two properties (NotifyPropertyChangedFor)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-toolkit

I have a question about C# new MVVM toolkit.

I wonder why this code works:

```cs
string MyProp => inputSystemName;  

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MyProp))]
private string inputSystemName;
partial void OnInputSystemNameChanged(string? oldValue, string newValue)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"InputSystemName changed from {oldValue} to {newValue}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"MyProp is now {MyProp}");
}
```

But this piece of code does not update the value of `myProp`:

```cs
private string myProp = String.Empty;
public string MyProp
{
    get => myProp;
    set => myProp = value;
}  

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MyProp))]
private string inputSystemName;
partial void OnInputSystemNameChanged(string? oldValue, string newValue)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"InputSystemName changed from {oldValue} to {newValue}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"MyProp is now {MyProp}");
}
```

It could potentially be my lack of understanding how the notify property works, but isn't it updating another property?

Thanks!

Comment: You get exactly what the name promised: A PropertyChanged **notification** for the given property. Thats it. Not more, not less.

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChangedFor` only declares that when the decorated property changes it must (in addition to its own PropertyChanged event)  raise the PropertyChanged event for the specified property. It does not assign any values to the property. Those whole attributes are only about PropertyChanged notifications. The generated properties automatically raise PropertyChanged for you. There is no further logic involved or injected. You would have to assign a e.g. computed value explicitly to the dependent property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That attribute doesn't set the property, it just raises an event to notify that it changed. So you'd need something like this snippet below to actually set the property.

```cs
        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MyProp))]
        private string inputSystemName;
        partial void OnInputSystemNameChanged(string? oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"InputSystemName changed from {oldValue} to {newValue}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"MyProp is now {MyProp}");
            MyProp = newValue; // set the new value to the related property
        }
```

That attribute will generate the following code

```cs
public string? InputSystemName
{
    get => inputSystemName;
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref inputSystemName, value))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProp");
        }
    }
}
```

You can see more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty#notifying-dependent-properties